# DataView.ToTable is not case-insensitive

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, case-insensitive, dataview

I am trying to create a DataView that has distinct rows that are case insensitive.

The  project is a list of XML files where the name is a concatenation of 4 user typed fields separated with a `_` character.  These are read and put into a string array with the `Split('_')` method and the initial table is created.  What we want is 4 separate listboxes with the unique case insensitive text strings in them so the user can select any of the file combinations. The user can set a sort and filter on any or all of the 4 sections.

```
AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1.xml

aaaa_bBBB_cccc_2.xml

Aaaa_BBbB_CcCC_3.xml

DDDD_EEEE_FFFF_1.xml

dddd_eeee_ffff_2.xml

DDdD_EeEE_fFFF_3.xml
```

Should produce these 4 listboxes with this data in them

```
AAAA  BBBB  CCCC   1

DDDD  EEEE  FFFF   2

                   3
```

Code for loading the first listbox

```
    DataView dv = _dtMasterDataBase.DefaultView;
_dtNames = dv.ToTable(true, new[] {Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4});
dv = _dtColumn1.DefaultView;

dv.Sort = ...a string containing 1-4 columns in Asc or Desc
dv.RowFilter = ...a string containing filters for 1-4 columns

_dtColumn1= dv.ToTable(true, new[] {Column1});
DataView dvColumn1 = _dtColumn1.DefaultView

ListBoxColumn1.DataSource = dvColumn1;
ListBoxColumn1.DisplayMember = "Column1";
```

What shows up in the first listbox is

AAAA

aaaa

Aaaa

DDDD

DDdD

Comment: It's not clear, do you want distinct rows according to all 4 columns or only the name column? Also, if you filter by the `Name` "Name" and the case doesn't matter the result would be a single row. Sorting by the column `Name` would also be pointless, so your pseudo code is just confusing. It would have been helpful if you'd have provided sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Also, if you have duplicate rows and you want to keep only one row of each name-group, which one do you want? The other columns could be different, which have priority?

Comment: I retyped the question with the actual example of what I am doing and the problem.  Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
string[] fileNames = { "AAAA_BBBB_CCCC_1.xml", "aaaa_bBBB_cccc_2.xml", "Aaaa_BBbB_CcCC_3.xml", "DDDD_EEEE_FFFF_1.xml", "dddd_eeee_ffff_2.xml", "DDdD_EeEE_fFFF_3.xml" };
HashSet<string>[] fourFields = new HashSet<string>[4];
string[][] allFields = fileNames
    .Select(fn=> Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Split('_'))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length == 4)
    .ToArray();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    fourFields[i] = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    for (int f = 0; f < allFields.Length; f++)
        fourFields[i].Add(allFields[f][i]);
}
```

The resulting array contains 4 `HashSet<string>`:

```
AAAA    DDDD
BBBB    EEEE
CCCC    FFFF
1       2       3
```

You could also fill a `DataSet` with 4 `DataTables` which makes it easier to use them as `DataSource`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add();
    HashSet<string> fieldset = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    for (int f = 0; f < allFields.Length; f++)
        fieldset.Add(allFields[f][i]);
    foreach (string field in fieldset)
        dt.Rows.Add(field);
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}
```

Every table has one column like `Table1`:

```
Column1
AAAA
DDDD
```